# Misconfigured system: how to increase swapfile for LVM disks?

Tags: 20.04, configuration, cpu-load

On an almost daily basis my laptop is stuck. In most cases I need to turn off the machine manually and restart it. In those cases CPU is very busy and memory seems to be used heavily.

*Memory: 8GB*

*CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7600U CPU @ 2.80GHz*

This happens, when I use different apps, like a browser, eclipse and Microsoft Teams, but the combination of running apps seems to be pretty random.

[image: Output of top]

~~Now I can see some processes are using very much CPU, but what exactly is `kswapd0` and `kworker`?~~ I guess, that my system is misconfigured, the current guess is that the swapfile is too small. How can this be increased / controlled?

```
$ uname -r
>> 5.4.0-54-generic

$ lsb_release -a
>> Description: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
```

**Edit regarding the swapfile in a LVM disks system**

```
~$ grep -i swap /etc/fstab
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0
```

`free -h` confirms, that my swapfile is `Swap: 975Mi` big.

**Edit**

Here is [the Linux bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/887793), but it seems to be marked as *invalid*. For whatever reason.

And a possible solution (not confirmed yet!): https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/887793/comments/170

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are kswapd0, kworker/num:num, ksoftirqd/num?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73639/what-are-kswapd0-kworker-numnum-ksoftirqd-num)

Comment: Against common belief, this is not normal, is not expected to go away by itself. It is a bug of linux. The post marked as a duplicate of this question, and many other accepted answers do not provide a solution. A fix for Ubuntu 12.04 worked for me on 19.10, and I need to do this up to 20.20. See accepted answer in https://askubuntu.com/questions/176565/why-does-kworker-cpu-usage-get-so-high.

Comment: @vanadium you mean, this is an 8 years old bug?

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `grep -i swap /etc/fstab` and `ls -alh /swapfile`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: The pos is eight years old indeed. I have the issue, and that tread helped me out. Looking at your screenshot, I would agree with heynnema that for you, it  looks rather looks like a memory problem than a kworker running away, so try the solution of heynnema first.

Comment: In "top", you can use > to sort on a different column (by default it sorts on CPU). Could be interesting to see where all your memory goes. I find it strange that a 8 GB RAM system is blocked by only firefox and eclipse.

Comment: @heynnema I've added the results for checking the swapfile, but I am confused. I have no idea, what the */swap/core ...* stuff is.

Comment: Oh, you're using LVM disks, and my answer wasn't for that configuration, so I had to delete my answer. The problem that needs fixing is that your swap (/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-swap_1) is too small. I don't know how to work with LVM disks. I'd suggest changing your question to "How do I increase swap on LVM disk configuration?", and see if you can set your swap size to 4G. That should fix your problem.

Comment: @vanadium Show me your `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution:

#### Create a new swapfile

I've tried to increase the size of the *swap_1* volume, but it failed. Probably because there was no space left in the volume group. I have used [these instructions](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-lvm-to-manage-storage-devices-on-ubuntu-18-04) and got something like

```
# fsadm: Filesystem "swap" on device "/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-swap_1" is not supported by this tool.
```

for

```
$ lvresize -L +5G --resizefs vgubuntu/swap_1
```

#### Swapfile

I have used [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1031300/336234).

Now I can see:

```
$ sudo swapon -s

# Filename              Type        Size    Used    Priority
# /swap_2               file        5119996 830464  -2
# /dev/dm-2             partition   999420  0       -3
```