# Heavy CPU Load IRQ Related

Tags: hp, cpu-load, top

Hey guys I'm curious as to what anyone here thinks. I have an HP Envy Laptop running Ubuntu 15.10 and it has a 4th generation quad core i7. For some reason since I first installed it my fan spins up, it gets hot and drains the battery quite quickly. I started digging and noticed that one of my CPU loads was at a constant high of 90%. I couldn't figure out why. I noticed that when a usb plug is plugged into the laptop this magically stops. With one not plugged in it spins right up. Any thoughts on why this might happen? I used `TOP` command in terminal and system monitor to determine this with pictures:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Here are some links to the research that I have done:

[8 CPU and one is at ~100% all the time](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289185/8-cpu-and-one-is-at-100-all-the-time)

[Why is ksoftirqd/0 process using all of my CPU?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7858/why-is-ksoftirqd-0-process-using-all-of-my-cpu)

Comment: Why does the research not help?

Comment: thanks for the comment, i dont know how to fix it basically. ive thgouth of downgrading to 15.04 maybe more stable less bugs ? I already updated to latest kernal 4.2.0-23. The links talk about key worker and ive already ran the perf and back traces to figure out what is taking the load which is IRQ stuff from usb but aside from plugging in a usb to make the cpu load come down, I dont have a permanent solution.

Comment: So  im on 15.10 now.

Comment: I doubt downgrading will help. Give me some time to look through those questions and I'll try and help.

Comment: Here the Perf report showing usb kworker related work

[IMG] http://tinypic.com/r/1z18xfr/9 [IMG]

Answer (score 0):

used powertop from the Ubuntu documentation pages and again pointed to usb/xhci stuff. but did not matter. i upgraded to kernel 4.4.1 and it stop doing the cpu load thing so i guess il never know 8(.

I was directed to this site by a coworker and it helped me incase it helps anyone:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/PowerManagement/IdentifyingIssues

PS: This page is useless
http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/boards-and-kits/000006243.html

Thanks all